# Capitalization of font names in CSS / HTML required?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I've been doing the codecadmy lessons on HTML / CSS and I'ma bit confused by capitalization.  It tells me always to remember to capitalize the font name but other times it's examples will show it lowercase.  For example codecadmy shows these examples as a guideline:

```
p {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

and

```
h1 {
    font-family: Times, serif;
}
```

Why is `Tahoma`, `Verdana`, and `Times` capitalized while `serif`, and `sans-serif` are lowercase?  Seems odd.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serif` and `sans-serif` are not font names, they are 'general style defaults' that will load a system (your local) default that matches said type.  `Serifs` are the `little curly bar things` on the end of characters.  `sans` is `French` for `without`.

Comment: That clears things up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So, Verdana, Times, and Tahoma are all actual fonts. They are the specific names of the fonts. So they are technically proper nouns in this case. For serif and sans-serif, it's a little different. These are just terms or what we would call common nouns. A font can be serif or sans-serif, but that isn't the actual name of it.

Answer (score 1):

Tahoma, Verdana and Times are actual font names, where as serif and sans-serif are placeholders for the default serif and sans-serif fonts on the user's computer. The default serif font is usually Times and the default sans-serif is Arial/ Helvetica depending on which OS the user has.

So if you want to include certain fonts into your webpage, then you would put the font name. However, if you didn't really care and just wanted to use the default fonts on the user's computer then you can put font-family: serif

Answer (score 0):

The case doesn't matter but "Tahoma", "Verdana", etc. are *names* of particular fonts, whereas "serif" and "sans-serif" are generic terms for certain font styles.